# How to query on ref in Faunadb?

Tags: faunadb

I have data like this

```
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("categories"), "1"),
  "data": {
    "title": "Game"
  }
}
```

And

```
[
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("courses"), "1"),
  "data": {
    "categoryRef": Ref(Collection("categories"), "1"),
    "courseTitle": "101",
    "description": "Some1"
  }
},
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("courses"), "2"),
  "data": {
    "categoryRef": Ref(Collection("categories"), "1"),
    "courseTitle": "102",
    "description": "Some2"
  }
},
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("courses"), "3"),
  "data": {
    "categoryRef": Ref(Collection("categories"), "2"),
    "courseTitle": "103",
    "description": "Some3"
  }
}
]
```

I just want to get all courses that belong to the selected category, in this case **game**

So result will be these.

```
[
    {
      "ref": Ref(Collection("courses"), "1"),
      "data": {
        "categoryRef": Ref(Collection("categories"), "1"),
        "courseTitle": "101",
        "description": "Some1"
      }
    },
    {
      "ref": Ref(Collection("courses"), "2"),
      "data": {
        "categoryRef": Ref(Collection("categories"), "1"),
        "courseTitle": "102",
        "description": "Some2"
      }
    }
]
```

Is this just a simple index on categoryRef and search in it? should I pass ref as FQL like this? `q.Ref(q.Collection('categories'), '1')`

Or maybe something like this which I don't know how to finish it.

```
q.Map(
    q.Paginate(q.Documents(q.Collection('courses'))),
    q.Lambda('courseDoc',
        q.Let({
            course: q.Get(q.Var('courseDoc')),
            categoryRef: q.Get(q.Select(['data', 'categoryRef'], q.Var('course'))),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an index to perform searching on collections of arbitrary size. Only small collections are amenable to the "table scan" approach.

If create an index, like this:

```
> CreateIndex({
  name: "courses_by_category",
  source: Collection("courses"),
  terms: [
    { field: ["data", "categoryRef"] },
  ],
})
```

Then you can search for course documents with a query like this:

```
> Paginate(
  Match(
    Index("courses_by_category"),
    Ref(Collection("categories"), "1")
  )
)
{
  data: [ Ref(Collection("courses"), "1"), Ref(Collection("courses"), "2") ]
}
```

To fetch the entire document for matching entries:

```
> Map(
  Paginate(
    Match(
      Index("courses_by_category"),
      Ref(Collection("categories"), "1")
    )
  ),
  Lambda("ref", Get(Var("ref")))
)
{
  data: [
    {
      ref: Ref(Collection("courses"), "1"),
      ts: 1663619044380000,
      data: {
        categoryRef: Ref(Collection("categories"), "1"),
        courseTitle: '101',
        description: 'Some1'
      }
    },
    {
      ref: Ref(Collection("courses"), "2"),
      ts: 1663619067090000,
      data: {
        categoryRef: Ref(Collection("categories"), "1"),
        courseTitle: '102',
        description: 'Some2'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```